# Flutter - ProxyProvider how to fix error "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Use case of the app:

- at App start, it will fetch a random User from a RestAPI,
- then it will use the result of the first call to make another RestAPI call, this is why I need ProxyProvider.

**main.dart:**

```
return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => RandomUser(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<RandomUser, FavoriteList>(
        create: (BuildContext ctx) => FavoriteList(ctx.read<RandomUser>()),
        update: (_, RandomUser user, __) => FavoriteList(user),
      ),
```

**RandomUser provider:**

```
class RandomUser extends ChangeNotifier {
  final apiUsers = UsersApi();
  UserModel? _profile;
  String? _userId;

  RandomUser() {
    fetchUser();
  }

  Future<void> fetchUser() async {
    await apiUsers
      .apiGetUser()
      .then((user) => {
        _profile = user,
        _userId = chosenUserId,
      })
      .catchError((e) {
        print("error: $e");
    });

    notifyListeners();
  }

  UserModel get profile => _profile;

  String get chosenUserId => _userId;
}
```

**FavoriteList provider:**

```
class FavoriteList extends ChangeNotifier {
  final RandomUser _user;
  final _apiFavoriteList = FavoriteListApi();
  List<FavoriteListModel> _favoriteList = <FavoriteListModel>[];

  FavoriteList(this._user) {
    fetchFavoriteList(_user.chosenUserId);
  }

  Future<void> fetchFavoriteList(String userId) async {
   await _apiFavoriteList
      .apiGetFavoriteList(userId)
      .then((favoriteList) => {
        _favoriteList = favoriteList,
      })
      .catchError((e) {
        print("error: $e");
    });

    notifyListeners();
  }
  
  List<FavoriteListModel> get favoriteList => this._favoriteList;
}
```

So as you can see, the `FavoriteList provider` needs the `RandomUser provider`, to retrieve the getter value `chosenUserId`

When I launch the App, I get right away the error "Null check operator used on a null value"
on the getter `chosenUserId` and in the `main.dart` where I call `"create"` of the `ProxyProvider`

What am I doing wrong?
Shouldn't the `ProxyProvider` first initialized the first `Provider`, so all the values I need are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `RandomUser.fetchUser()` has not completed before `FavoriteList` is created. You should code allowing for this situation, e.g. in `RandomUser`:

```
  String? get chosenUserId => _userId;
```

and in `FavoriteList`:

```
  final? RandomUser _user;

  FavoriteList(this._user) {
    if (_user != null && _user?.chosenUserId != null) {
      fetchFavoriteList(_user.chosenUserId);
    }
  }

  String? get chosenUserId => _user?.chosenUserId;
```

When `fetchUser()` completes then `FavoriteList` will be updated.

Your UI will have to cope with the (temporary) missing data, of course.

BTW the documentation for [ChangeNotifierProxyProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider-class.html) suggests that you should structure your code like this:

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<MyModel, MyChangeNotifier>(
  create: (_) => MyChangeNotifier(),
  update: (_, myModel, myNotifier) => myNotifier
    ..update(myModel),
  child: ...
);
```

In that situation, if MyModel were to update, then MyChangeNotifier will be able to update accordingly. Notice how MyChangeNotifier doesn't receive MyModel in its constructor anymore. It is now passed through a custom setter/method instead.

Comment: first of all thank you for the answer! I tried implementing this, and the check you do in the constructor of FavoriteList, to check if _user is not null, gives me this warning: The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.
Remove the condition., why is that?

Comment: FYI I also had to update my initial post, as the getter method for chosenUserId was written wrong, the code I'm using is: String get chosenUserId => _userId;

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention to null safety - the warning is saying that `_user` cannot be null, so the check is redundant. I updated the answer to allow `_user` and `chosenUserId` to be null. The changes should work now.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm getting closer, now the error is gone, there is still one point, when you launch the app, there will be a first call to "fetchFavoriteList(_user.chosenUserId);" which will fire with the userID param being null, then after a couple of sec it will refire with the param correctly set. I don't understand why it's being fired for the first time with the Param as Null, when we put a if( _user != null), meaning if it enters that If, it means the _user object is available right?

Comment: and FYI in =>  fetchFavoriteList(_user.chosenUserId);, I had to add a "?" after _user, otherwise it throws: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: Ok maybe I solved, I changed the FavoriteList constructor to this: FavoriteList(this._user) {
    if (_user != null && _user?.chosenUserId != null) {
      fetchFavoriteList(_user.chosenUserId);
    }
  }

basically I added a second check in the if() clause, now it won't fire my Fetch method until all data is available, is this the correct practice here? thank you very much

Comment: That is what we want, I edited the answer. (Sorry again that I did not test with null safety enabled.)

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

my code was like this

```
providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => Auth()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          create: (ctx) => Products(null, null, []),
          update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
              auth.token! ,
              auth.userId! ,
              previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => Cart()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
          create: (ctx) => Orders(null, null, []),
          update: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) {
            print(auth);
            return Orders(auth.token!, auth.userId!,
                previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders);
          },
        ),
      ],
```

and fix that by change `!` to `??` like this code

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          create: (ctx) => Products(null, null, []),
          update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
              auth.token ?? null,
              auth.userId ?? null,
              previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items),
        ),
```